# Where is the instance of MainActivity? What is its name?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building an app using Android Studio (and using Kotlin code). As with many such apps it includes a class for MainActivity, as well as a number of other classes that I have defined.

When I debug/run the app I can see that the code within the MainActivity class is executed, which I assume means that the app has created an instance of the MainActivity class so it's executing such things as the onCreate function. But where is that instance of the MainActivity class? What is it named?

I would like to access, from other classes, some of the functions and variables that I have defined within the MainActivity, but in order to do that I need to know the name of the instance that (apparently) gets instantiated automatically when the app starts running.

Comment: "But where is that instance of the MainActivity class?" -- it is created and managed by framework code. Think of your app as being a glorified plugin for a framework. "in order to do that I need to know the name of the instance that (apparently) gets instantiated automatically when the app starts running" -- that is not how Android app development works, sorry. Books and courses on Android app development can show you how to structure your code.

Comment: Class instances don’t have names. Variables and properties have names, but they are reference holders, not the instances themselves. There’s nothing stopping you from passing your activity reference out to other classes or assigning it to a property by passing `this` from inside it, but if you do this, you will create memory leaks, so you shouldn’t.

Comment: In addition, you're assuming there's only 1 instance of MainActivity.  There can be more.  Put it in the background and bring it back 5 minutes later, you're probably in a new instance.  Rotate the phone and briefly there will be 2 at the same time.